# would concatenating javascript files prevent individual files from caching?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to weigh the advantage of concatenating over using js loaders.
Say If I have page 1 with javascript file 1 & 2 and I concatenate both of it and on the second page I have javascript file 2 & 3 and I concatenate both of it and send it ..would this prevent caching of 2nd javascript on the client side. if i had send the scripts on page 1 as js1 & js2 then js2 would have got cached on the client side and when page2 comes in it would not request js2 since it is got it already. so it will request only js3.

so which is a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: You could probably make this really interesting or complicated with localStorage as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would not *prevent* caching, but it would cause needless over-caching.

You would end up with two cached js files, each of which contained a large block of the same code.

You should keep the script files separate, and allow the client to cache them separately.

Comment: thanks for the response...but why is everybody talking about concatenating js files..I have like 20 - 25 js files and each page has a permutation and combination of these files. so I am not sure if I should combine and throw it or let it live as separate call and use js loader in which case I have to take care of the sequence and inline calls have to be wait..

Comment: You might actually have an arcitectural problem with your js code itself, if you can't just bundle your whole js app into a smallish number of files. If the bulk of the code is expected to be used over the course of a session on the site, you should bundle it together, actually. But not in a way that duplicates things.